# Is there an "undelete queue"?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, undeletion

**Now Undeleted**

I have [a question deleted by Community](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1529750/290189) due to `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.  I tried editing it so that it becomes on-topic, and I casted "undelete" and "reopen" votes to my question.  However, the system says that I needed 4 more undelete votes to undelete my question.  I checked the review queue, and there's no queue of post pending for undeletion.  Is there a queue for others to review that change?

Comment: Not a queue like the other review queues. But recent votes to delete/undelete can be viewed in [Review->Tools](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days) menu. A catch is that you need 10k+ rep points to see it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: One might add that one also needs 10k to vote (except OP and mod), so it is consistent. // Usually and also in your case one needs a total of three undelete votes. There is also a [dedicated thread for such requests](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio)

Comment: @quid Thank you for your comment.  Should I also make a post there?

Comment: Since indirectly you already have drawn attention to it in this specific case I see no need to post there too, at least not right away.